# Font-awesome...hover not working why?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Below is the code. I tried to make hover work in Font-awesome. But it doesnot!! Please help..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
   .icon-facebook-sign:before {color:lightblue;}
   .icon-facebook-sign:hover{color:red;}
   .icon-twitter-sign:hover{color:#00BEF6}
   .icon-google-plus-sign:hover{color:red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<li style="float:left;">
    <!-- start social bookmarks -->
    <div style="font-size: 32px; color: grey;">
    <i class="icon-facebook-sign" style="color:red; margin-left: 0px; :hover{color:lightblue;}">               
</li>
   <i class="icon-twitter-sign" style="margin-left: -12px;"></i>
   <i class="icon-linkedin-sign" style="margin-left: -12px;"></i>
   <i class="icon-google-plus-sign" style="margin-left: -12px;"></i>
   </div>
   <!-- end social bookmarks -->
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

I executed this from :  http://jsbin.com/idicib/3/edit

Comment: What is not working? Elaborate. Plus, when I hover on your social Icons, I can see the hover effect.

Comment: Where is ur problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here You added only the `font-awesome` but not `twitter-bootstrap`. Add this link to your code and try. It will work `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
   .icon-facebook-sign:before {color:lightblue;}
   .icon-facebook-sign:hover{color:red;}
   .icon-twitter-sign:hover{color:#00BEF6}
   .icon-google-plus-sign:hover{color:red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<li style="float:left;">
<!-- start social bookmarks -->
<div style="font-size: 32px; color: grey;">
<i class="icon-facebook-sign" style="color:red; margin-left: 0px;   :hover{color:lightblue;}">               
</li>
   <i class="icon-twitter-sign" style="margin-left: -12px;"></i>
   <i class="icon-linkedin-sign" style="margin-left: -12px;"></i>
   <i class="icon-google-plus-sign" style="margin-left: -12px;"></i>
   </div>
   <!-- end social bookmarks -->
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the demo: http://jsbin.com/idicib/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the jsbin that you have provided.

http://jsbin.com/idicib/5/edit

When I removed some styles from your code it started working.
:before and the inline style for :hover was creating the problem.

Hope this is what you want.